Could we update bit column in PolarDB?
I am using PolarDB 8.0. I have a bit column in my table:
IsDeleted bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0'
I tried to update this bit column by using:
UPDATE t_order_profit_total SET IsDeleted = b'1' WHERE ( OrderId = 538001524793413 );
But I hit following error
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'IsDeleted' cannot be null
Any idea why?
IsDeleted bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0'
This column is not not null and it has a default value '0'.
Hence it could not be null.
